# Prolog unifying two lists

Tags: prolog

Alright, so I was trying to unify this two lists: `[2]` and `[1,_,3]` giving an answer of `[1,2,3]`. My code is below:

```
unify([],[],_).
unify(List1, [Head|Rest], List2) :- member(List1,Head),!,
                                         unify([X|_], Rest, [X|List2]).
unify(List1, [Head|Rest], [Head|List2]) :- unify(List1, Rest, List2).
```

when i put `?-unify([2],[1,_,3],L)` it gives me false, but I want it to give `L=[1,2,3]`. How can I improve the above code?

I tried a trace too but I couldn't figure out.

```
[debug] 5 ?- unify([2],[1,_,3],L).
T Call: (6) unify([2], [1, _G512, 3], _G520)
T Redo: (6) unify([2], [1, _G512, 3], _G520)
T Call: (7) unify([2], [_G512, 3], _G602)
T Call: (8) unify([_G607|_G608], [3], [_G607|_G602])
T Redo: (8) unify([_G607|_G608], [3], [_G607|_G602])
T Call: (9) unify([3|_G608], [], _G602)
T Fail: (9) unify([3|_G608], [], _G602)
T Fail: (8) unify([_G607|_G608], [3], [_G607|_G602])
T Fail: (7) unify([2], [_G512, 3], _G602)
T Fail: (6) unify([2], [1, _G512, 3], _G520)
false
```

Comment: You want to be careful with the terminology to be clear. You cannot *unify* the list `[2]` with the list `[1,_,3]` because they are of different length. You probably mean you want to unify the *element(s)* of list `[2]` with variable *element(s)* in the list `[1,_,3]`, which is saying something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix the base case: rather than using

```
unify([],[],_).
```

which says that an empty list on the left requires an empty list in the middle, and produces an undefined result, use these two:

```
unify(_,[],[]).
unify([],L,L).
```

The first base clause says that if the second list is empty, the output is empty as well, no matter what's in the first list.

The second base clause says that when the first list is empty, the output is the same as the second list.

Now we need to build two clauses that reduce the problem:

```
unify([H|T1], [H|T2], [H|R]) :- unify(T1, T2, R).
unify([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H2|R]) :- H1 \= H2, unify([H1|T1], T2, R).
```

The first clause says that if the heads of the two lists unify, then attach the unified heads to the output of the reduced problem when both lists are reduced.

The second clause says that if the heads do not unify, then attach the head of the second list to the output of the reduced problem when only the second list is reduced.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/djXECf).

Comment: You are such a genious!! By using the same variable `H` you can see if they unify right? So you don't need the predicate `member`. Another thing, when you wrote the 2º predicate why test again if they unify `H1\=H2`?

Comment: @Miguel "when you wrote the 2º predicate why test again if they unify `H1\=H2`" That's a very good question! The answer is that if they do unify, this rule should not apply. I could have done it using the cut `!` in the body of the first rule, but then the readability would suffer, because the readers would need to read other non-base clauses to understand the last clause. This is often considered bad - in fact, some Prolog programmers consider cut "the GOTO of Prolog".

Comment: I got it! It is true that the way you wrote it's easier to understand, and it is more appealing. Thank for the time spent.